# How to create 100 instances of model automatically after the creation of new model?

Tags: python, django

I work on cinema booking app. I've already created table in frontend, contains 100 seats (10 rows x 10 seats). Each seat is "td". I thought about making each td an object of the model so I can easily assign users later on. Basing on main model's max_seats i want to create the objects. After adding a new movie to db the objects should get created automatically. Any idea or hint where to start ?

My main model:

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    max_seats = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

And the model where i need to create the objects:

```
class Seat(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    row = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with your current `ForeignKey` and create seats in `views.py` or anywhere else in your code. You can also access list of seats using `getSeatsList` function below:

Your movie model:

```py
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    max_seats = models.IntegerField(default=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Movies, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Change Movies field if necessary here

        for i in range(self.max_seats):
            new_seat = Seat()
            new_seat.customer = None
            new_seat.movie = self
            new_seat.row = i%10 + 1
            new_seat.number = i + 1
            new_seat.save()


    def getSeatsList(self):
        return list(self.movie_seats.all())
```

And your seat model:

```py
class Seat(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    # Adding a Foreign Key with a related name
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='movie_seats', null=True, blank=True)
    row = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Or alternatively, in your `views.py` or anywhere else when you create a new Movie, you can create a list of seats and assign them to your movie:

```py
new_movie = Movies()
new_movie.title = "New Title"
new_movie.price = 20
new_movie.max_seats = 100
new_movie.save()

for i in range(new_movie.max_seats):
    new_seat = Seat()
    new_seat.customer = None
    new_seat.movie = new_movie
    new_seat.row = i%10 + 1
    new_seat.number = i + 1
    new_seat.save()
```

Comment: Looks okay, but can it be done automatically ? I mean once I have added new movie via admin panel, the objects of Seat with foreign key to this movie are getting created ?

Comment: @husa It is possible by configuring `__init__()` function. But you should be aware after that, it will always create seats even if in some cases you don't want to create those seats. I have updated the code

Comment: IntegrityError at /admin/main/movies/
NOT NULL constraint failed: main_seat.customer_id :/ What this could be ?

Comment: @husa That's for the `customer` field in your `Seat` model. When you create a seat, no customer should be assigned to this field. You can edit it to accept `Blank` or `Null` fields. I've updated the code again